# Interactive terminal in VIM

Tags: linux, vim, ide

I'm using Vim for editing source code, but I would also like to have a terminal embedded in vim's window (just like in Kate, you know).

Now I have seen the vimsh plugin that turns a vim buffer into an interactive terminal, but I don't like 2 things about it:

1. It opens automatically at startup. Can I disable it and invoke the terminal with a special command whenever I wish?
2. It splits the window in two and occupies the top window, but I would like it to occupy the bottom window. Can this be arranged?

PS: I'm not exactly a vim guru :)

Comment: This question is completely on-topic here. One of the four appropriate topics for questions listed in the FAQ is "software tools commonly used by programmers", and Vim+shell clearly qualifies. It should never have been necessary, but this has even been [confirmed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su). Please don't mark questions as off-topic if you haven't read the FAQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want: [Conque Shell - VIM Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771)

Answer (score 0):

There's also an older *patch* that you can apply. It requires recompilation of the VIM source code though.

- http://www.wana.at/vimshell/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not going to reply exactly to your question but I'll propose anyway a different approach on working with Vim and the terminal.

The first approach is to run shell commands directly from vim in command mode prepending them with a "!":

```
:!ls
```

will run the shell **ls** command and display you the output in a temporary window. This is useful if you just want to run a single or few commands.

If you want to mess around longer I suggest to suspend your vim session with **Ctrl-z**, work in the shell and issue **fg** as your last command to get back to vim.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could try is using tmux/screen to split your terminal, so that you can then run vim in one pane and have your shell in another. I also liberally use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to drop into a shell from vim and then `fg` to get back to vim after finishing with the shell.